# Rails + React + Relay server side rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, relay, isomorphic-relay

In the project I'm working on we are using [react-on-rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) application. Here is [tutorial with demo](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial) how to use this application with basic React Rails Redux Webpack stack. It fully supports server rendering. But for my project we need to support Relay and I submitted [PR to tutorial repo](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/pull/328) with Relay demo implementation. Right now it doesn't support server rendering and I found [isomorphic-relay-router](https://github.com/denvned/isomorphic-relay-router) written especially for this purpose. It has an example how to use it with node.js backend, but I need to use it with Rails backend. I did few attempts to adopt this application, but without success. Can anybody guide me how to do this or give some advice?

It's easy to install tutorial demo with Relay support following [these instructions](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial#basic-demo-setup) and using my repo (with Relay example, no server rendering) instead of original for the 2 step:

...

2. `git clone -b relay git@github.com:ramusus/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.git`

...

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Very interested. Thanks!

Comment: No any success. I found relay uses async javascript code, which make impossible to render it on the backend side.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try with a timeout? It would be imperfect, but maybe get the job done?

Comment: I don't remember I tried it.